# Using Notepad++, how can I add multiple suffixes to one prefix?

Tags: notepad++, regex

So I have a list of 3,125 inputs as such:
`fdfffff`,
`fdffffd`,
`fdffffs`,
`fdffffa`,
`fdffffg`.
Each input starts with `fd` but then a random combination of the letters `f` `d` `s` `a` and `g` to fill in the next 5 characters up until the `@`.

Now what I want to do is add multiple suffixes:
`@100.com`,
`@101.com`,
`@103.com`,
`@104.com`, so on and so forth up until `@199.com`.

For a visual representation of what I want in case I didn't explain very well in text:
`fdfffff@100.com`
`fdfffff@101.com`,
`fdfffff@102.com`, all the way through to:
`fdggggg@199.com`.

So each input should have 100 separate suffixes, equaling a total of 312,500 outputs. (3125*100). Can I do this using Regular Expression in Notepad++? Could I regular expression using something along the lines of `fd[0-9]{5}@1[0-9]{2}.com` where regex fills in the numbers for me in the replace tab rather than combining 2 lists many times?

Sorry if this is confusing and not explained properly, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This is not possible with regexp. You could try using the [Python Script - Plugin for Notepad++](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I don't think Regular Expressions are a good way to solve this kind of problem. I would suggest using a scripting language like Windows Batch, Bash or Python and taking advantage of their `for` loops

Answer (score 1):

This perl oneliner does the job:

```
perl -e 'for $x(glob"{f,d,s,a,g}{f,d,s,a,g}{f,d,s,a,g}{f,d,s,a,g}{f,d,s,a,g}"){print "fd$x\@$_.com\n" for(100..199)}' > outfile
```

where:

- `glob"{f,d,s,a,g}{f,d,s,a,g}{f,d,s,a,g}{f,d,s,a,g}{f,d,s,a,g}"` produces the list of all combinations of 5 letters.